# Emacs won't run certain commands on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp

So I have this Emacs plugin which I quite like:

`auto-indent-mode`

However, when I add it to my startup file (_emacs) like this:

`(auto-indent-mode)`

It won't run.

Also, I would like to know how I could setup my Emacs window like this:

`-----------
 |  A   | B|
 |______|  |
 |    C |  |`

Thanks.

Comment: The beta emacs.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, how would I get it moved

Comment: Stack Overflow also works.  Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" [are on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, and I'd say Emacs definitely qualifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mode appears to be buffer-local. If you always want this mode enabled, EmacsWiki [suggests doing this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentMode#toc4):

```
(auto-indent-global-mode)
```

You can also enable it for certain modes, e.g.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'auto-indent-mode)
```